# Tensor library in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing code in C++ and I have to work with tensor objects. My tensors have very large dimensions and they are predominantly dense. Mainly I have to deal with reshaping (unfolding tensor), n-mode product and summation of tensors.

Do you suggest me any particular library for my specific case?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is matrix enough or you need tensors of any index length?

Comment: any index length!